# How to get two variables similarly scaled?

Tags: python, data-science, data-preprocessing

I am currently working on Maritime ship data for predictions. In preprocessing stage I am asked to transform Length(meters) variable to scale with Gross_Tonnage variable.
The formula of Gross Tonnage is given by GT = Volume(cubic meters) x K

where K is a multiplier. More about Gross Tonnage can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross_tonnage)

I am completely lost how to transform the Length variable. I know that Volume is in Cubic Meters whereas Length is in linear meters. How can I transform Length variable to get this done?
[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question.

Comment: To get cubic meters you need three dimensions, such as length, breadth, and height (or depth).  The product of these (LxBxH) is the volume of a 3-D rectangle (cubiod) which you'd scale by a density factor K to get the GT estimate.  Since length is already in meters it seems there's no scaling to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to normalize the two columns so the values fall in the same range, you could apply the following transformation to both columns independently:

```
(X - X_min)/(X_max - X_min)
```

This will scale both columns to fall within the range 0 and 1. This is called MinMax scaling. *Sklearn* has a function that does this.

```
# import the function 
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler

# fit scaler on your data
X_norm = MinMaxScaler().fit(X)
```

*X* is going to be your column, so you will be applying it to both columns separately.